# Accessing the same function from two different classes

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes, suppose A and B. Within B, I instantiate A.

I have a function `func()` that is required by both the classes.

How should I go about it? I had thought of this approach:

```
class A:
   func()

class B:
   x = A()
   func()

def func():
```

And then I can access func() from within A or B. Is this approach OK or is there a better way to do this (perhaps using an OO approach)

Note that I am new to OO programming and that is why I am interested in knowing whether I can apply any OO design to this.

Edit: The function can differ in the arguments it takes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling method from a class in a different class in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311987/calling-method-from-a-class-in-a-different-class-in-python)

Comment: What's with that wacky syntax? Why are you calling a function inside a class declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Define `func` before you define either class, and it will be available to both.

Comment: Is this is a good practice as such? Or this is a result of poor design.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the simplest way of doing it, and as the Zen of Python states, ``Simple is better than complex.``

Comment: @Chris: Could be good, could be bad. It depends on what func is and what the classes are. In Python, module-level functions like this are not illegal like they are in Java (though I should note that Java folks have several patterns that work around this), and module-level functions do get used quite a bit in the standard Python libraries, for example.

Comment: Generally, it's good. Module-level functions are standard practice in Python.

Comment: Functions that are generic and don't require to be bound to a class are great for being globally available in the module, moreso if it has potential uses outside of the scope of it's own module (parts of your application using the code from the module can also find use for it)

Answer (score 0):

func here can me a method of common base class

```
class Base(object):
    def func():
        #...
class A(Base):
    #...
class B(Base):
    #...
```