# Call Class Method From Another Class

Tags: python

Is there a way to call the method of a class from another class? I am looking for something like PHP's `call_user_func_array()`.
Here is what I want to happen:

```
class A:
    def method1(arg1, arg2):
        ...

class B:
    A.method1(1, 2)
```

Comment: Does that really need to be a class method and not a function?  Static methods in other languages don't necessarily map to a class method in Python.  Give this a read: http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Comment: @Ivo Honestly, what do you care if he writes his own MVC before he learns the basics? let him try and  learn the basics in the process. quit being so condescending to people asking questions.

Comment: maybe duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311987/calling-method-from-a-class-in-a-different-class-in-python

Answer (score 78, accepted):

update:  Just saw the reference to `call_user_func_array` in your post. that's different. use `getattr` to get the function object and then call it with your arguments

```
class A(object):
    def method1(self, a, b, c):
        # foo

method = A.method1
```

`method` is now an actual function object. that you can call directly (functions are first class objects in python just like in PHP > 5.3) . But the considerations from below still apply. That is, the above example will blow up unless you decorate `A.method1` with one of the two decorators discussed below, pass it an instance of `A` as the first argument or access the method on an instance of `A`.

```
a = A()
method = a.method1
method(1, 2)
```

---

You have three options for doing this

1. Use an instance of `A` to call `method1` (using two possible forms)
2. apply the `classmethod` decorator to `method1`: you will no longer be able to reference `self` in `method1` but you will get passed a `cls` instance in it's place which is `A` in this case.
3. apply the `staticmethod` decorator to `method1`: you will no longer be able to reference `self`, or `cls` in `staticmethod1` but you can hardcode references to `A` into it, though obviously, these references will be inherited by all subclasses of `A` unless they specifically override `method1` and do not call `super`.

Some examples:

```
class Test1(object): # always inherit from object in 2.x. it's called new-style classes. look it up
    def method1(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    @staticmethod
    def method2(a, b):
        return a + b

    @classmethod
    def method3(cls, a, b):
        return cls.method2(a, b)

t = Test1()  # same as doing it in another class

Test1.method1(t, 1, 2) #form one of calling a method on an instance
t.method1(1, 2)        # form two (the common one) essentially reduces to form one

Test1.method2(1, 2)  #the static method can be called with just arguments
t.method2(1, 2)      # on an instance or the class

Test1.method3(1, 2)  # ditto for the class method. It will have access to the class
t.method3(1, 2)      # that it's called on (the subclass if called on a subclass) 
                     # but will not have access to the instance it's called on 
                     # (if it is called on an instance)
```

Note that in the same way that the name of the `self` variable is entirely up to you, so is the name of the `cls` variable but those are the customary values.

Now that you know how to do it, I would seriously think about *if* you want to do it. Often times, methods that are meant to be called unbound (without an instance) are better left as module level functions in python.

Comment: what is significance of cls in `@classmethod
    def method3(cls, a, b):
        return cls.method2(a, b)`

Comment: The use of `getattr` here is utterly pointless. `A.method1` is equivalent, simpler, and faster. `getattr` is only useful when the attribute name to access is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 20):

Just call it and supply `self`:

```
class A:
    def method(self, x, y):
        print(x + y)

class B:
    def call_a(self):
        A.method(self, 1, 2)

b = B()
b.call_a()
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: this example is wrong as you are passing class B reference to class A method

Comment: I guess it will work as long as all attributes referred as self.x in the method also exist on B

Comment: @VarunMaurya, Python uses duck typing, so classes aren't checked. As a1an says, long as you supply an object with the correct attributes this will work.

Comment: @ratiotile I'm getting "TypeError: unbound method m() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
"

Comment: @oak, I don't know what version of python you are using, but the example was in Python3: https://repl.it/repls/DecentPurpleBsddaemon

Answer (score 6):

```
class CurrentValue:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def set_val(self, k):
        self.value = k

    def get_val(self):
        return self.value


class AddValue:

    def av(self, ocv):
        print('Before:', ocv.get_val())
        num = int(input('Enter number to add : '))
        nnum = num + ocv.get_val()
        ocv.set_val(nnum)
        print('After add :', ocv.get_val())


cvo = CurrentValue(5)

avo = AddValue()

avo.av(cvo)
```

We define 2 classes, CurrentValue and AddValue
We define 3 methods in the first class
        One **init** in order to give to the instance variable self.value an initial value
        A set_val method where we set the self.value to a k
        A get_val method where we get the valuue of self.value
We define one method in the second class
    A av method where we pass as parameter(ovc) an object of the first class
We create an instance (cvo) of the first class
We create an instance (avo) of the second class
We call the method avo.av(cvo) of the second class and pass as an argument the object we have already created from the first class.
So by this way I would like to show how it is possible to call a method of a class from another class.

I am sorry for any inconvenience. 
This will not happen again.

Before: 5

Enter number to add : 14

After add : 19

Comment: It would help if you added further explanation, so readers would know why your answer was a good one. Code only answers are not always clear to novice readers.

Comment: you got typo on "ocv.get_val()" . should it be cvo instead of ocv?

Answer (score 3):

You can call a function from within a class with:

`A().method1()`

Comment: If A had already inherited from somewhere else (say "Red"), would I need to include the base class inside A?  i.g. A(Red).method1()

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but no, that is not required.

Answer (score 2):

In Python function are first class citezens, so you can just assign it to a property like any other value. Here we are assigning the method of `A`'s hello to a property on `B`. After `__init__`, hello will be attached to B as `self.hello`, which is actually a reference to A's hello:

```py
class A:
    def hello(self, msg):
        print(f"Hello {msg}")
    
class B:
    hello = A.hello

print(A.hello)
print(B.hello)

b = B()
b.hello("good looking!")
```

Prints:

```
<function A.hello at 0x7fcce55b9e50>
<function A.hello at 0x7fcce55b9e50>
Hello good looking!
```

Comment: Why is this answer negatively rated? It seems like a cleaner way to reassign a method to another class

Answer (score 0):

Better you make an object of the required class then call that object.method instead of Class.method