# Calling a method of one class in another class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to call `test_check_footer_visible` in another `.py` file.

`origin.py` has:

```
class FooterSection(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    """
    browser  = None
    site_url = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser.open(self.site_url)
        self.browser.window_maximize()

        # make footer section
        self._footer = FooterPage(self.browser)

    def test_check_footer_visible(self):
        #press the page down
        self.browser.key_down_native("34")
        self.browser.key_down_native("34")
        self.browser.key_down_native("34")
        print "Page down"
        time.sleep (10)
```

Now in `dest.py` I need to call `test_check_footer_visible()`. How do I do that?

`dest.py` has the following format:

```
class TestPageErrorSection(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    """
    browser  = None
    site_url = None

    def setUp(self):
        global SITE_URL, BROWSER

        if not BROWSER:
            BROWSER = self.browser

        if not SITE_URL:
            SITE_URL = self.site_url

        BROWSER.open(SITE_URL)
        BROWSER.window_maximize()
        print 'page not found 404 error'
        self._pageerror_section = ErrorSection(BROWSER)

    def _primary_navigation(self):
        # I want to call test_check_footer_visible here.
```

I tried everything in [Call Class Method From Another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856413/call-class-method-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can't (without doing some really shady things -- see comments by @glglgl) -- at least not without changing your code somewhat.  The reason you can't is because `test_check_footer_visible` will assert that the first element passed in is an instance of the class `FooterSection` (which it isn't -- it's an instance of `TestPageErrorSection`).  You have (at least) a couple of options for the re-factor.

1) Make `TestPageErrorSection` inherit from `FooterSection` and use that function directly (e.g. `self.test_check_footer_visible()` *This doesn't seem like a very good option to me based on the class names*

2) Make `test_check_footer_visible()` a regular function.  It can then be called from either class.

3) Create a 3rd class (e.g. `SectionBase`), put `test_check_footer_visible` on that class and have your other 2 classes inherit from it.

Comment: Not exactly - it can be made possible with `FooterSection.test_check_footer_visible.im_func(self)`, but it would be VERY bad style - for 2 reasons: 1. because it is bad style as such and 2. because the callee is intended to get a `self` from a completely different class. But it would work. This just for completeness.

Comment: @glglgl -- Yes, I suppose that would work.  It's a little twisted to do it that way.  Essentially, that is a very shady way of implementing #2 I suppose ...

Comment: Yes. Essentially, it undoes the process done by making the function a method... `FooterSection.__dict__['test_check_footer_visible'](self)` would work as well, but now it gets weird.

Comment: @glglgl I implemented FooterSection.test_check_footer_visible.im_func(self) - it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I have one more question though: 

Let us assume that in origin.py I have 

def testing_again(self):
  #call test_check_footer_visible()

And in dest.py I have the lines

FooterSection.testing_again.im_func(self) it does not work.

Comment: @Anuradha -- how did you import origin?  if you do `from origin import FooterSection` in dest.py, I would expect it to work.  If you just did `import origin`, you'd need `origin.FooterSection.testing_again.im_func(self)`.

Comment: @mgilson...Thanks. I did from origin import FooterSection.. but unfortunately it did not work