# Pyunit framework extending the classes of unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

In Pyunit framework, I have question as below:

```
import unittest

class xyz(object):
    def test_fuc(self):
        print "test_fun"
        pass

class abc(unittest.Testcase, xyz):
    def setUp(self):
        print "setUp"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "tearDown"

    def test_one(self):
        print "test_one"
        pass

    def test_two(self):
        print "test_two"
        pass
```

**Output:**

```
test_one

test_two

test_fun
```

but I need output like below:

```
test_one

test_fun

test_two

test_fun
```

Please suggest, How do I do it?

Comment: why the `pass` in the method definition?

Comment: sorry, this is just an example what I wrote above. I just want to know how we do it.. I am trying to google but cant find the solution. thanks for your help

Comment: & what i might ask you are trying to do? Its not clear from your question

Comment: I want to run test in the extended class (i.e. class xyz) for every tests that runs in the base class (i.e. class abc)..

Comment: So, once it runs the "test_one", it should run "test_fun". And then "test_two" followed by "test_fun" and so on...

Comment: then call that class in every method of the base class

Comment: I cant do that, if I try to run "def test_one(self, xyz)" - it throws an argument error.

Comment: create an object of the other class & using that object call the class

Comment: is this what you said "ob = xyz() ob.test_fun()" - this doenst extend my test of the base class (abc).

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3856502/2276527) is what I'm trying to tell you

Comment: nah, it doesnt seems to work. there should be another way!

Comment: Once the base class test is run, it should run the test of the extended class. creating object and calling using that obj doesnt extend the test.

Comment: anybody can provide some input on this. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests (ie. `unittest.TestCase` methods) are supposed to be independant, and thus  there is no point of running them twice.

If you want to do that, you probably should design your tests another way.

Comment: I mean, I have designed according to the pyunit framework, but I just want my derived test to run for every base test. thats all my requirement is about.

Comment: or is there a why to call a testcase from another testcase