# Pyunit skip setUp and tearDown methods for a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is it possible to skip the setUp and tearDown functions for a test..? Please let me know how. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without writing another test class with different `setUp` and `tearDown` methods seems to be to overwrite the `run` method of `TestCase`.
You can either rewrite it totally or try this shorter version (only for the `setUp`, but you can easily extend it to support `tearDown` too):

```
class MyTestCase(unitest.TestCase):
    def run(self, result=None):
        if self._testMethodName == 'testWithoutSetup':
            (old_setUp, self.setUp) = (self.setUp, lambda : None)
            try:
                super(MyTestCase, self).run(result)
            finally:
                self.setUp = old_setUp
        else:
            super(MyTestCase, self).run(result)
```

What I do is I test if the method being tested is named `testWithoutSetup`, and if it is, I temporaly replace the `setUp` method with a function that does nothing.

Note that I only tested with Python 3.3, and it may work only for this version.

Comment: oh yea got it.. I have got another question which I posted here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144990/pyunit-framework-extending-the-classes-of-unittest), if anybody could answer that it is really helpful. thank you