# Calling a Class function from another Class

Tags: python, wxpython

My limitations are my worst enemy, but bestest learning buddy.

I have two classes:

```
class WorkerThread(Thread):
"""Worker Thread Class."""
def __init__(self, notify_window):
    """Init Worker Thread Class."""
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self._notify_window = notify_window
    self.ToKill = False
    self._want_abort = 0
    self.start()

def run(self):
    """Run Worker Thread."""
    while worker==True:
        # somehow get to volumePanel.startStop() 

        if self.ToKill == True:
            return None
    proc.wait()
    wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent(None))
    return
```

And:

```
class VolumePanel(wx.Panel):
    #<...snip...>
    def launchVolClick(self, event):
        if self.bt_Launch.Label == "Enable Monitor":
            self.worker = WorkerThread(self)
            self.bt_Launch.Label = "Disable Monitor"
        else:
            self.worker.ToKill = True
            self.bt_Launch.Label = "Enable Monitor"

    def startStop(self):
        print "in def startStop()"
```

I want to find a way to call `startStop` from within the `WorkerThread`.  I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856413/call-class-method-from-another-class) and couldn't get it to work either.

**EDIT: Final working code below**

```
class WorkerThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    def __init__(self, notify_window, func):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self.ToKill = False
        self._want_abort = 0
        global function
        function = func
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        while worker==True:
            # somehow get to volumePanel.startStop() 
            function()
            if self.ToKill == True:
                return None
        proc.wait()
        wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent(None))
        return

    def launchVolClick(self, event):
        if self.bt_Launch.Label == "Enable Volume Monitor":
            self.worker = WorkerThread(self, self.startStop)
            self.bt_Launch.Label = "Disable Volume Monitor"
        else:
            self.worker.ToKill = True
            self.bt_Launch.Label = "Enable Volume Monitor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a reference to `startStop` and call the reference from within the thread class as one option. Without seeing more code / how your code is structured it's hard to say for other options.

Here's a contrived example of the former. You don't have to pass things around this way you could call the thread in `VolumePanel` and pass `self.startStop`.

Also, `worker` is undefined and so is `proc` unless this if some part of `wxpython` which I'm not familiar with.

```
from threading import Thread

class WorkerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, func):

        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func

    def run(self):

        for i in range(10):
            self.func()

class VolumePanel:

    def __init__(self):

        #self.thread = WorkerThread(self.startStop)
        #self.thread.start() #or elsewhere
        pass

    def startStop(self):

        print "in def startStop()"

vp = VolumePanel()
thread = WorkerThread(vp.startStop)
thread.start()
```

Comment: I can pass the `def startStop` to `WorkerThread(Thread)`?  I added the event that starts the `WorkerThread` above to see if that helps with clarity.

Comment: You sparked what I needed to know -- I added `func` to the `__init__` declaration and added a global and it worked. :)  Updated, working code, above.

Comment: If you make it an attribute, you don't need the global. `self.function` and `self.function()`. Also `return` is unnecessary at the end of `run`. You can merge your two conditions to avoid the `return None`. `while worker and not self.ToKill`

Answer (score 0):

You can also passs the calling class to the thread like so:

```py
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            wx.CallAfter(self.parent.startStop)


class VolumePanel(object):
    def startStop(self):
        print "in def startStop()"
```

Notice that we use `wx.CallAfter()` instead of just calling the function directly. This is because if we call it directly, it's actually being called from the thread instead of the `MainThread`. This can sometimes be a problem depending on whatever you're doing.

If we print out the current thread (with `threading.current_thread()`) without `wx.CallAfter`, we get

```py
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
<WorkerThread(Thread-1, started 6612)>
```

However, with `wx.CallAfter`, we get

```py
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 6604)>
```