# How do I call a class method from another file in Python?

Tags: python, member-functions

I'm learning Python and have two files in the same directory.

`printer.py`

```
class Printer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 'yo'

    def printMessage(self):
        print self.message

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printer = Printer()
    printer.printMessage()
```

How do I call the `printMessage(self)` method from another file, `example.py` in the same directory? I thought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856502/270847) was close, but it shows how to call a class method from another class within the same file.

Comment: Have you imported `printed.py`?

Comment: The multiple downvotes on this question make me a little angry. I was a beginner just over 3 years ago and figuring out this question- even after reading SO post after SO post- was a source of great frustration for me. How to use the import system is VERY difficult to figure out for a beginner who is trying to learn on their own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to import it and call it like this:

```
import printer as pr

pr.Printer().printMessage()
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `printMessage` is not static. You need to create an instance of the `Printer` class.

Comment: You are calling a class method without argument. I guess you meant `pr.Printer().printMessage()`

Comment: @ChristianK. yeah, just fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

@Gleland's answer is correct but in case you were thinking of using one single shared instance of the `Printer` class for the whole project, then you need to move the instantiation of `Printer` out of the `if` clause and import the instance, not the class, i.e.:

```
class Printer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 'yo'

    def printMessage(self):
        print self.message

printer = Printer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printer.printMessage()
```

Now, in the other file:

```
from printer import printer as pr
pr.printMessage()
```

Comment: No, you can't call an unbound method without the instance as argument.

Comment: I am not calling an unbound method. Please have a look again. The only difference with the other @gleland's answer is that I import the instance, not the class.

Comment: @KlausD. could you please revise your comment and undo the negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

In the example.py file you can write below code

from printer import Printer

prnt = Printer()

prnt.printer()