# How can I call a method which is in another class under another file in python?

Tags: python

How can I call a method which is in another class in another fie under same package,  from my python file?

Comment: Please post your code and your package structure.

Comment: If they are in the same directory, you could import it directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a class method from another file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395630/how-do-i-call-a-class-method-from-another-file-in-python)

Comment: In module (file) `a`, import the other module (file) `b`: `import b`.  Then in module `a` create an object `o` of class `c` which is defined in module `b`: `o = b.c()`.  Then call the method `m` in object `o`: `o.m()`.  Keep in mind that a module of name `a` is in a file of name `a.py`.

Answer (score 2):

You would first need to import the file (depending on your directory structure) into your current script, create an instance of the class and then call the method within that class;

```
#Import your other file
import other_file

#Create an instance of the object where your method is
my_obj = NewClass()

#Call the method directly
my_obj.some_method()
```

You could also try adding a @staticmethod to the method to make it directly callable:

```
class NewClass:

    @staticmethod
    def some_method():
        print 'Hello'

#call staticmethod add directly 
#without declaring instance and accessing class variables
NewClass.some_method()
```

Comment: fro eg : if i call the method with the help of self , like self.my_obj.some_method() inside my method's(my_method) in my main class it will say "my_method' object has no attribute 'my_obj"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. However you don't call any methods within a class using self, all calls to a method are in the format of  `object.method()`

Comment: else if i call it without using self , i call it by my_obj.some_method() it shows                            "error unbound method some_method() must be called with NewClass instance as first argument"

Comment: are you using Python 2.7? Also we really need to see some code otherwise it could be a multitude of things, including user error.

Comment: thanks for the help , but understand through the comments  , i tried to explain you the error by using the above example itself , and really thank you for the help

Comment: You could also try adding a @staticmethod decorator to your method, then it will be callable. I will add to my answer now.