# python - how to properly import a method from a class in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here. I'm having problems trying to import and/or use a method from a class that I've created which I created a "/lib" directory for.

Here is my current file tree:

```
/tokenmgt
         /lib/myToken.py
```

From the directory:

```
/tokenmgt
```

I am running the python from the command line in this directory.
I want to use the "create" method defined in my class "TokenMgr":

```
class TokenMgr():
    """Model a Token Manager"""

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def create(self, privkey, email):
        """<REST OF CODE HERE>"""
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lib.myToken
>>> from lib.myToken import create
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'create' from 'lib.myToken' (C:\Users\FOO\Desktop\MyWork\dev\lib\myToken.py)
```

Do I need to also import the class name ("TokenMgr" defined in the .py script? I'm confused how to do this properly. Thanks

Comment: possibly something like: `import myToken.TokenMgr` granted the other file you want to make use of this method is within the same directory level.

Comment: @FishingCode - thx. I got a little farther. But when I use the class it, it says NameError: name 'create' is not defined

Comment: I'm calling it like so -  my_token = create(private_key,'foo@gmail.com')

Comment: ah, ok. I think it has to be something like `import myToken.TokenMgr as tokenMethod` tokenMethod can be anything you want and then call the `create` like so: `tokenMethod.create()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395630/how-do-i-call-a-class-method-from-another-file-in-python).

Comment: @FishingCode You actually need to instantiate the class here.

Comment: That's correct, yep, needs to instantiate the `TokenMgr()` before calling the specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to import and use a class:

```
from lib.MyToken import TokenMgr
manager = TokenMgr()
manager.create(private_key,'foo@gmail.com')
```

Note the second line, in which we create an *instance* of the class.

Comment: Thank you @bensha - your reply and answer solved my immediate need to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

The create method can be accessed only through an object. So you should import your class, create an instance and then do instance.create().. if you feel the create should not be tied to any object u can decorate it using @classmethod, so that you can access without an object..

Here are a bit of basics. Pythons classes can have three types of routines.

1. Instance methods -> These are tied to an  object, they receive self as the first argument, which is the object
2. Class methods -> Which are common for all objects of a class, and the first argument is cls for these methods instead of self
3. Static methods -> They are also tied to a class, but they neither receive class or object instance as their first argument. This is as good as having a standalone function, outside a class definition.

2 and 3 are achieved with @classmethod and @staticmethod decorators respectively like below:

In [6]: B.create(10)
In static create method..

```
In [7]: class A:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def create(cls,x):
   ...:         print("In create method with args {},{}".format(cls, x))
   ...:
   ...:

In [8]: A.create(10)
In create method with args <class '__main__.A'>,10


In [4]: class B:
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def create(x):
   ...:         print("In static create method..")
   ...:

In [6]: B.create(10)
In static create method..
```

In your case you can use either of them based on your requirement or create an object of the TokenManager class and then call create method  like below:

```
tokenManager_obj = TokenManager()
tokenManager_obj.create()
```

Comment: This is all correct, but especially as the OP is a newbie, you need to give some more detail about how they would actually do this.

Comment: @alaniwi - thanks. Yes, I am trying to learn both how to import properly and use a class. So any simple example would be appreciated. thank you all