# Calling a class in another way

Tags: c#, .net

I am just a beginner and I am trying to learn other alternatives.

Is there another way to call a class from another class. For example, I have a class called Test, can you call it in another way from this one = Test example = new Test();

Comment: You can "call" a class in different ways depending on it's type. For example, if the class is static (or has static functions), you can call its static members directly like `Test.MyFumction();` without `new`. Share your code if you need more help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Class Method From Another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856413/call-class-method-from-another-class)

Comment: There are no alternatives here. Each way is for a different purpose. The way you mentioned in your question is for a specific purpose that cannot be achieved in any other way.

Comment: Hi, maybe you mean instantiate a new class?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Type Factory class which can create an instance for you dynamically. Read some articles about type factory. 
Its a very common way to dynamically create instances of a type.

Lets say you have a program that generates text files. As parameter you can ask for a specific template, the program should then browse through your classes of type text generator and create an instance matching your requested template.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an instance of this class i.e this is **not a static class** then

```
Test example = new Test();
```

is the correct way to call this class.

If this was a static class e.g `public static Test {...` then you could call this class without creating a new instance of it e.g **Test.SomeMethod** [Example Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74ce7b/static-class-in-C-Sharp/)